# SQL. This one involves multiplying two columns from different tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

First I have to find the Salesman ID, salespersons names (first and last), their SIN number, the quantity sold, the unit price and the total $ in sales (and I have to label this field as TotalSales) for each product.

Here is the data:

[image]

Here is what I have done so far, let me know if it is wrong:

```
SELECT 
    s.SalesmanID, s.FirstName, s.LastName, s.SIN, 
    ps.QuantitySold, ps.UnitSalesPrice, 
    (this is where I’m stuck, I must have to create a new column called TotalSales here)
```

Let me know if you can help!

Comment: Are you familiar with what INNER and OUTER joins are? (serious question).

Comment: Is the sellid and saleamanid the same thing? Is their a relationship between the two?

Comment: @patelb they are considered equal yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT s.SalesmanID, max(s.FirstName) first_name, max(s.LastName) last_name, max(s.SIN) sin, sum(ps.QuantitySold) sold_qty, sum(ps.quantitysold * ps.UnitSalesPrice) total_sales_AMT from salesmen s join productsales PS on s.salesmanid = PS.sellerid group by s.salesmanid
```

You need to do a join with a group by in order to total the sales quantity and sales prices at the salesman level. See code above.

The reason for the join and group by is because i assume that there is a one to many relationship between the salesmen and productsales.

If you need to do it at the salesman and product level then you want to expand the grouping. See below.

```
SELECT s.SalesmanID, ps.productid, max(s.FirstName) first_name, max(s.LastName) last_name, max(s.SIN) sin, sum(ps.QuantitySold) sold_qty, sum(ps.quantitysold * ps.UnitSalesPrice) total_sales_AMT from salesmen s join productsales PS on s.salesmanid = PS.sellerid group by s.salesmanid, ps.productid
```

One more note is that replace the join with a left outer join if you want to get all salesmen and not only the ones that had a sale

Comment: Thanks @patelb Can you explain how and where a new field (TotalSales) was created using the UniteSalesPrice multiplied by the QuantitySold?

Comment: I missed that multiplier. I made the edit. Check the code blocks now.